# Carousel Cards not working using dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

i have a problem in carousel cards, its not working with me on the first click.

i also add an intent for "actions_intent_OPTION" but its not working with me also, i referred to the docs but the are handling a simple response i need when clicking on the cards to take the key and display an intent not a simple response.

any one can help me please. thanks

```js
app.intent('action.intent.OPTIONS', async (conv, option, params) => {
    console.info('option --------------- ', option, typeof option);

    const str = option.toString()
    switch (str) {

        case 'The Exams Dates': {
             triggerExamsDateIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        
        case 'Entrance exam': {
            triggerEntranceExamIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        
        case 'majors': {
            triggerMajorsIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Courses': {
            triggerCoursesIntent(conv);

            break;
        }
        case 'Ask Question': {
            triggerAskQuestionIntent(conv);

            break;
        }
        case 'MobileDevelopment': {
            triggerMobileDevelopmentIntent(conv);

            break;
        }
        case 'Partial': {
            triggerPartialIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Entrance Exam Sample': {
            triggerSampleExamIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Dont Have Questions': {
            triggerDontHaveQuestionsIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Exams Schedule': {
            triggerExamsScheduleIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Final': {
            triggerFinalIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'second round': {
            triggersecondroundIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'MIS': {
            triggerMISIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Banking': {
            triggerBankingIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Marketing': {
            triggerMarketingIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Accounting': {
            triggerAccountingIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Management': {
            triggerManagementIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'About Entrance Exam': {
            triggerAboutEntranceExamIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'About Exam': {
            triggerAboutExamIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Required Documents': {
            triggerRequiredDocumentsIntent(conv);
            break;
        }
        case 'Partial Schedule': {
            triggerScheduleIntent(conv, 'Partial Schedule');
            break;
        }
        case 'Final Schedule': {
            triggerScheduleIntent(conv, 'Final Schedule');
            break;
        }
        case 'Second Schedule': {
            triggerScheduleIntent(conv, 'Second Schedule');
            break;
        }

        default: {
            conv.ask('Response not set for this item!  \n   please set response first');
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `params` parameter is passed before the `option` information. So that should be

```
app.intent('action.intent.OPTIONS', async (conv, params, option) => {
```

Comment: ohh yes it works, thank you a lot dear you made my day <3

Comment: Great! If an answer helps, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.